# Is there any way to add numbers to a "buffer" in a while-loop?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++, and at the moment i am trying to make a calculator that calculates a Euklid's Algorithm.

Anyways, what i need help with is how i can add the final number to some kind of array for each loop.

Lets for example say i put in the numbers 1128 and 16. my program will then give this output

```
1128 % 16 = 70 + 8
70 % 16 = 4 + 6
4 % 16 = 0 + 4
```

theese three lines is printed, one at the time, for each loop. What i want is to add the last numbers (8, 6 and 4) to an array. How would i do this?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::vector<int>::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Yes there is. There are plenty of class template [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in the standard library. Take into account the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of array, Hope this Helps!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a=1128,b=16,i;
    vector<int>arr;
    while(a>b)
    {
        cout<<a/b<<" "<<a%b<<endl;
        arr.push_back(a%b);
        a/=b;
    }
    cout<<a/b<<" "<<a%b<<endl;
    arr.push_back(a%b);             // Case: When a<=b in Vector
    for(i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";         // Array i.e 8 6 4
    return 0;
}

Output:
70 8 
4 6
0 4
8 6 4   // Array
```

Comment: Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to above site. More reliable source of information.

Comment: @ishpreet but gcd(1128, 16)=8...?

Comment: @pmaxim98 The program is not calculating **Gcd**. Just have a look again you will find soon. Hint: **b** is not changing in each loop iteration.

Comment: @ishpreet I know but I think he is looking for something like that since he said in the question that he wanted 'a calculator that calculates a Euklid's Algorithm'.

Comment: @pmaxim98 But his examples and expected result depicts something else.

Comment: @ishpreet Indeed. I guess he's trying to figure out the algorithm. Well, I hope after he manages to undestand it, he could directly use `std::gcd` instead of writing his own version.

Comment: I know this can be calculated pretty easily other ways, the reason i'm doing it this way is because i want to print out the whole process of calculating it

Also, what my program does is using Euklids Algorithm to convert a number to a HEX-number in this case. (there is probably better terms for this, im not english)